# Connecting solar panel to a USB controller

Tags: soldering, solar-cell, wiring, solar-charge-controller

I am a complete beginner in this area so please excuse me if my question is stupid (I am just starting and have a lot to learn). English isn't my first language so pardon me if I make any mistakes (or don't express myself properly).

I have a small 12W 6V solar panel like on picture below (picture 1) with 2 cables (positive and negative). When the cable is stripped, it looks like picture 2. I don't know how it is called in English, but you can see a bunch of tiny copper wires in there.

[image]
[image]

Next, I have a small solar USB controller that stabilizes the output to 5V, like shown on image 3.

[image]

Now I would like to connect those cables to solar controller, but I have no idea how to do it. If there were less wires in the cable, I could solder them to the +/- on solar controller board, but like this... I have no idea...

Any help would mean a lot!

Comment: Start by finding a keyboard with a working shift key to be able to capitalize the first letter of each sentence, I and names. Then get your multimeter and measure which lead is + and which is -. Most likley the inner white one is + and the other sleeve is -.

Comment: thanks for the help dude, will consider it ;) and if i may, small advice for you, before answering, at least try to understand the question :)

Comment: Go and read the Wikipedia article on wire.

Comment: @Joskosa hint: if someone with much experience tells you they haven't correctly understood your question, then the right reaction would be to edit and clarify the question, not trying to be a smart-ass towards that someone who tried to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soldering such a thick multi-stranded wire won't be a good idea. Best choice would be to use crimp wire terminals.

[image]